# Haskell basic function definition

Tags: haskell

I'am learning haskell and I don't realy understand function definitions, for example:

```
module TestModule where

iter :: Int -> (a -> a) -> (a -> a)

iter n f 
  | n>0         = f . iter (n-1) f
  | otherwise   = id

iter_2 n f = foldr (.) id (replicate n f)
```

What I suppose to give this function? I have loaded this function via console and don't really understand how to use it.

My question how to use this function via console. Like "iter 5 ???"

Comment: [GHCi](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html). What do you mean 'use this function via console'? You said you've loaded it already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give it *a function*, more specifically, an *endofunction* (mapping any type to itself). For example,

```
*Main> iter 3 sqrt 256
2.0
```

Of course, this can also be a custom function, like

```
*Main> let f x = x+2
*Main> iter 3 f 7
13
```

or even an anonymous one defined right in the invocation:

```
*Main> iter 3 (\str -> "("++str++")") "..."
"(((...)))"
```

Comment: Many thanks!!! And can you give an example of this: "interleave :: Stream a -> Stream a -> Stream a"?

Answer (score 4):

read the type of the function as

```
iter :: Int -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
        ^^^    ^^^^^^^^    ^    ^
        arg      arg      arg  result
```

meaning if you provide an `Int`, a `(a->a)` function, and an `a`, it will give you back another `a`.  Here `a` stands for any type.  For example

```
iter 4 (+1) 0
```

will be `4`, that is performs `(+1)` on `0` four times.